# show text inside of template after selection (with text-field and value-field)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I'm working with `BootstrapVue`.

I have a `b-form-select` where I show my `name` *(= text field)* inside the selection in my child.vue and `emit` my `age` *(=value field)* to my parent.vue. This works well.

Now I also want to `show` my `name`, so my *text-field* in my `child.vue template` - how can I achieve that?

For now I'm using `watch` to detect changes when something is selected and `emit` this `value`.. but here I also want to check my `text-field` and "print" it below my `b-form-select`.

*My template (child.vue)*

```
<b-form-select v-model="selected_Person" :options="persons" text-field="name" value-field="age"></b-form-select>
<div> {{ Here I want to see the name of my Person }} </div>
```

*My script (child.vue)*

```
data() {
  return {
    persons: [
      {"name": "Hagrid", "age": "81"},
      {"name": "Harry", "age": "18"},
      {"name": "Ron", "age": "19"},
      {"name": "Snape", "age": "48"}
    ],
    selected_Person: null,
  }
},

watch: {
  selected_Person() {
    this.$emit('selected_Person', this.selected_Person) //Here I emit my age, because it's my value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Method-1:** Swapping `text-field` and `value-field` values

```
<b-form-select v-model="selected_Person" :options="persons" text-field="age" value-field="name"></b-form-select>
<div> {{ selected_Person }} </div>
```

**Method-2:**

You can use `computed` property for this like

```
<b-form-select v-model="selected_Person" :options="persons" text-field="name" value-field="age"></b-form-select>
<div> {{ getPersonName }} </div>
```

and

```
data() {
  return {
    persons: [
      {"name": "Hagrid", "age": "81"},
      {"name": "Harry", "age": "18"},
      {"name": "Ron", "age": "19"},
      {"name": "Snape", "age": "48"}
    ]
  }
},
computed: {
 getPersonName() {
  return this.persons.filter(person => person.age == this.selected_person)[0].name; // logic is applicable only when you set value-field to `age`
 // In case if there are multiple persons with the same age then use the below code
 // return this.persons.filter(person => person.age == this.selected_Person).map(per => per.name).join(',');
 }
},
watch: {
  selected_Person() {
    this.$emit('selected_Person', this.selected_Person) //Here I emit my age, because it's my value
}
```

Comment: Text-field applies only within the select box, if you want to display that in an outer div then try with computed.
Else instead of mapping `age` in the value field, map `name` in the value-field and `age` in the text-field therefore you will able to see it on the div

Comment: Hi, it works logically, but actually I can't declare my selected solution before.. like you have done it with ```[0]```.. how can I check the "real" selected person?

Comment: the `[0]` logic that I have written works only when you set `value-field` as "age". If you are setting `value-field` as "name" then follow method-1

Comment: ```return this.persons.filter(person => person.age == this.selected_person)[0].name;``` this code line only gives me the first data of my json, but I want to show it based on my selection.. [0], [1].. is not the solution I need..

Comment: Nope it won't, try selecting the age 18 in the select box, and you will be able to see the name corresponding to that

Comment: Method 2 - First solution is hardcoded and doesn't affect anything when I select something in my code because ```[0]``` only selects data on place 0. Method 2 - Second solution will print all ```names``` in my template.. I'm sorry but it don't work out..

Comment: if you see carefully I have applied `.filter` in that statement (ie) the resultant array will contain only those persons who's ages are equal to the selected_age!

Answer (score 0):

How are you binding v-model to a watcher?? I think the watchers are used to watch a particular value in your `data()` property. You should define a 'selected_Person' property in your data() and watch that value and consequently you can display in the `template` like this: -

```
data() {
  return {
    persons: [
      {"name": "Hagrid", "age": "81"},
      {"name": "Harry", "age": "18"},
      {"name": "Ron", "age": "19"},
      {"name": "Snape", "age": "48"}
    ],
    selected_Person: null
  }
},

watch: {
  selected_Person() {
    this.$emit('selected_Person', this.selected_Person) //Here I emit my age, because it's my value
}
```

In the template: -

```
<b-form-select v-model="selected_Person" :options="persons" text-field="name" value-field="age"></b-form-select> 
<div> {{ selected_Person }} </div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry of course I define it in my data (```selected_Person: null```).. I've just reproduced my code because otherwise it would be to big to show it.. changed it in my question.. But at least ```selected_Person``` would show my age (=value) and not my name(=text-field)

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: @patrick96 Yes for that the answer above fulfills your requirement. You can use computed property for that.